# Triggered Send Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have this scenario.

Subscribers/people signup for an event (web form), and system should store their info in Data Extension and send an welcome email for those who registered.

I was able to create a landing page and insert the web form (Smart Capture) and populate the registered user data to a Data Extension.

But while trying to send a triggered email to that data extension it is not populated in triggered Data Extension.

so i created a triggered data extension but i am not able to populate data into this data extension , there is no primary key in triggered DE.

Please help me

Answer (score 3):

I got caught out by this as well. Setting up the new Data Extension as copy from the Triggered Send template made everything work perfectly.

It's not something that's made very clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SFSE.  If you configure your Triggered Send Definition to write to a Data Extension based on the Triggered Send template, you don't need to write to a separate data extension first -- simply pass your additional form attributes in your triggered send API call.  As long as the attribute names match the target Data Extension, they'll get recorded.

[Data Extension Procedures - How to Create a Data Extension from a Template](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/procedures/)

Comment: I am  new to exacttarget. how to configure triggered send API call?

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: [Triggering an Email](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/#Triggering_an_Email)